# How to run a XCTest automatically every X day/week?

Tags: ios, cron, xctest

I have created a `XCTest` that I'd like to run automatically every day. I have been thinking of a cron job or something like this, but I really have no idea of how to do that and where to start.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use a cron job for that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

Are your tests running on CI or locally ?
On Jenkins or Gitlab CI for example you can define [scheduled jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html), or you can have a cron job like you said, you can also use Xcode server, more informations here :
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. My tests are only running locally... I was thinking of creating something like a local daemon.